# Как получить значение по ключу из вложенного массива?

Tags: php, laravel

В Laravel с помощью построителя запросов получаю коллекцию **$cena_put**,

```
$product1 = $cena_put->whereIn('id', 71484);
```

но у неё индекс каждый раз меняется при перезагрузки страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел способ получить доступ к вложенному массиву с помощью **foreach**:

```
foreach ($product1 as $item)
        {
            print_r($item->cena);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($cena_put);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
```

Однако способ с **foreach** мне не совсем нравится, есть ли другой способ получить значение из вложенного массива, минуя его индекс, ибо он генерируется каждый раз по новой при перезагрузки страницы, и возможно ли это?

Comment: В вашем случае, похоже что нужно привыкать к циклу foreach. Он вам сильно облегчит жизнь. Использовать индексы будет плохой практикой - вы в разы ухудшаете читабельность кода.

Comment: Напишите, что вам именно не нравится в foreach применительно к вашей задаче? Возможно есть более правильное решение.

Comment: Мне не нравится использование foreach ради получения одного элемента из массива, как по мне это не слишком профессионально, метод с first() мне нравится гораздо больше

Comment: Используйте метод find()  $product1 = $cena_put->find(71484);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у Вас есть переменная `$items` типа `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

#### Вариант №1

Как верно заметил @u_mulder, если Вам просто нужно получить первый элемент - вы можете воспользоваться методом `first`

```php
$first = $items->first();
```

#### Вариант №2

Если Вам нужно получить массив с более подходящими для работы ключами, то вы просто можете получить список значений коллекции без привязки к старым ключам с помощью метода `values()`. Фактически это обертка над функцией `array_values`(см документацию https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values)

Таким образом Вы можете получить массив со всеми значениями(без сохранения прежних ключей) и там уже у вас будут обычные ключи, начинающиеся с нуля (0,1,2,...);

И получить элемент можно будет по индексу 0,1,...

```php
$first = $items->values()[0];
$second = $items->values()[1];
// ...
```

#### Вариант №3

Также вы можете получить все значения коллекции с помощью метода `all()` и уже над этим массивом пытаться проводить эксперименты. Например с помощью `array_key_first` узнать ключ первого элемента.
И получить его из коллекции по индексу или же получить массив всех ключей с помощью функции `array_keys`(https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php)
и получать нужные ключи по все тем же ключам 0,1,2,...

```php
$all = $items->all();

$firstKey = array_key_first($all);
$first = $items->get($firstKey);

$keys = array_keys($all);
$second = $items->get($keys[1]);
$third = $items->get($keys[2]);
// ...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, метод first() мне как раз подошел